# Algebraic Closure of the field of rational functions

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, galois-theory, fields

Using the theorem of Puiseux, one concludes that the algebraic closure of $\mathbb C(X)$ is the set of algebraic elements (over $\mathbb C(X)$) of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb C((X))$, which is $\cup_n\mathbb C((X^{1/n}))$. 
I have two questions:

- Is there any direct description of this field?
- What is the Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb C(X)}/\mathbb C(X))$?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by «direct» description? $\bigcup_n\mathbb C((X^{1/n}))$ seems pretty direct to me…

Comment: @AmitH: I think you meant the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{C}((X))$. Every finite group appears as Galois group over $\mathbb{C}(X)$, by the Riemann existence theorem.

Comment: The Galois group of $\overline{\mathbb{C}(X)}$ over $\mathbb{C}(X)$ is the free profinite group over the set $\mathbb{C}$. See for instance "Algèbre et théories galoisiennes" by R. and A. Douady, no. 6.4.

Comment: @matthias yes, thanks for correcting. deleted my comment.

Comment: @Loïc Teyssier, $\cup_n\mathbb C((X^{1/n}))$ is not the algebraic closure of $\mathbb C(X)$

Comment: I have got the reference (Algèbre et théories galoisiennes, page 363) thanks @abx.

Comment: @AllyMath, sorry, I read the sentence too fast.

Comment: Over finite fields, there is a description due to Kedlaya: https://eudml.org/doc/249608 .

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318690